# How do I delete rows in Excel based on values in column B and C

Tags: python, excel, vba, pandas

I have 15,000 rows in the below spreadsheet and I need to keep the rows:

*where status > 0 and lastvalidationattemptdistance < 50*

[image: Spreadsheet]

Comment: Check out [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org).

Comment: Can't a simple filter help here? You really don't need to program anything, just activate the filter option and filter for status an lastvalidationattemptdistance columns. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I thought that it would not take into account the fact that column A,B and C are related but it worked, thanks. Now I have to count how many times a userid appears in column A, thoughts?

Comment: use `CountIF()` built in excel function

Comment: Not sure the CountIF() would work because I have to do it for all userId! Basically I need to see how often every userId appears in column A and then calculate the average reappearence of every userId.

Answer (score 2):

Simple data manipulation in [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html). It's really simple and useful, you can learn it in 10 min.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('excel.xlsx', 'sheet_name', index_col=None, na_values=['NA'])

df = df.loc[df['status'] > 0]
df = df.loc[df['lastValidationAttemptDistance'] < 50]

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('new_execel.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, 'sheet_name', index=False)
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use VBA in excel to delete what you need then find a UserId.

```
Sub Delete()
'
' Delete and Find Macro
'


    Dim aRows As Integer, LVAD As Integer, Stat As Integer, UserId As Integer, UIDCount As Integer
    Dim Rng As Range, Rng2 As Range

    LVAD = 50 'Min value to keep
    Stat = 0 'Min value to keep
    UIDCount = 0 'Initial count number
    UserId = 3526 'Exact number of userId

    With ActiveSheet
    aRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    For i = 1 To aRows
        If Range("B" & i).Value <= 0 Then
            If Range("C" & i).Value > 50 Then
                If Rng Is Nothing Then
                    Set Rng = Range("A" & i & ":C" & i)
                Else
                    Set Rng2 = Range("A" & i & ":C" & i)
                    Set Rng = Application.Union(Rng, Rng2)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

    For i = 1 To aRows
        If Range("A" & i).Value = UserId Then
            UIDCount = UIDCount + 1
        End If
    Next

    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        Rng.Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
    MsgBox "UserId: " & UserId & " was found " & UIDCount & " times."
End Sub
```

To count the userId for each user individually you could count all unique id's then do a loop iteration for each one to count the occurrences, then maybe set those values into columns.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use Excel for Windows, consider an SQL solution by connecting to the Jet/ACE SQL Engine (Windows .dll files usually installed on most PCs and the very engine of MS Access). You can use your exact criteria in a `WHERE` clause. No `For` looping or nested `If` logic or formula is needed.

Below assumes data resides in a sheet named `DATA` and an empty worksheet named `RESULTS` exists in workbook which will hold the output of the SQL query including headers. Two connection types are included namely ODBC Driver and OLEDB Provider. Simply change path to Excel data file.

```vb
Public Sub RunSQL()
    Dim conn As Object, rst As Object
    Dim strConnection As String, strSQL As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    ' DRIVER AND PROVIDER CONNECTION TYPES
'    strConnection = "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" _
'                      & "DBQ=C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsm;"
    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
                       & "Data Source='C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsm';" _
                       & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"";"

    strSQL = " SELECT * FROM [DATA$]" _
                & " WHERE [status] > 0 AND [lastvalidationattemptdistance] < 50;"

    ' OPEN DB CONNECTION
    conn.Open strConnection
    rst.Open strSQL, conn

    ' COLUMN HEADERS
    For i = 1 To rst.Fields.Count
        Worksheets("RESULTS").Cells(1, i) = rst.Fields(i - 1).Name
    Next i    

    ' DATA ROWS
    Worksheets("RESULTS").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst

    ' CLOSE OBJECTS AND FREE RESOURCES
    rst.Close: conn.Close
    Set rst = Nothing: Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```